# Are number of characters to be deleted and number of characters to be added to make a string palindrome equal?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I went through 2 questions - 
1. Find minimum number of insertions required to make a string palindrome?
2. Find minimum number of deletions required to make a string palindrome?

When I approached it recursively, both the recurrence relations were same,
For example - "abcda" Insertions 2(adcbcda), Deletions 2(aca)

```
int minCharsToDeletePalindrome(const string& str, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo == hi) {
        // Single character is always a palindrome
        return 0;
    }

    if (hi == lo + 1) {
        if (str[lo] == str[hi]) {
            return 0;
        }
        // This means there are only characters left now, 2 chars always need only 1 character to delete such they 
        // become a palindrome.
        return 1;
    }

    if (str[lo] == str[hi]) {
        return minCharsToDeletePalindrome(str, lo + 1, hi - 1);
    }
    else {
        // Added one because we have already deleted one character in both the cases.
        return min(minCharsToDeletePalindrome(str, lo, hi - 1)
            , minCharsToDeletePalindrome(str, lo + 1, hi)) + 1;
    }
}
```

Logically looking **they should be equal**, because the characters to be deleted are the characters which hamper the string from becoming a palindrome and hence if a I add the same characters to string then the string should become palindrome, or I can do other way round.

So am I inferring it correctly or is there any instance when they would no be equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'll always be equal. Let S be the input string and P be the palindrome you make by adding k characters, where k is the min where this is possible. Find the reflections of these k additions in P (symmetric across the center of P). Deleting those reflections from S results in a palindrome. Thus min_deletions <= min_insertions. Flipping the argument gets min_insertions <= min_deletions, so these must be equal.

E.G., say the original string is AXBYA. The min number of insertions is 2: AX(Y)BY(X)A, insertions in parens. The minimum deletions is 2: ABA, where we delete the reflections of the two letters we inserted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What I understood from Comment is -
Suppose I am given a string S ->"abc"  P->"acbca" k -> 2
Deleting reflections from S -> "b" 
Example 2 - S -> "abcd" P->"abdcdba" k->3
Deleting Reflections S->"c"
This always returns a single character which in itself is a palindrome.
But how does it represent "min_insertions <= min_deletions" or "min_deletions <= min_insertions"
Please correct if I am wrong anywhere in my understanding?

Comment: @SagarSharma Deleting reflections will not always result in a single character. I gave an example. The point is that if adding k characters will get you a palindrome, then deleting the reflections of those k characters will too, and vice versa.